# Create custom component wrapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am migrating react code to typescript and have one issue with type custom component wrapper.
I am sending `as` prop, from which i will create component and use it as JSX. By default it is set to `div` but also it can be React component, specifically custom `Link` component, which return `RouterLink` from `react-router-dom` or `a` tag.

Current code

```
function DropdownMenuItemWrapper({
  as ='div',
  to,
  target,
  onClick,
  active,
  children
}) {    
  const Wrapper = as ;

  return (
    <Wrapper
      to={to}
      target={target}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Issue is, i do not know, how to type `as` property and how to use `Wrapper`. If i try something like:

`const Wrapper = React.createElement(as);` or just `const Wrapper = as;`

i got error: `JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Answer (score 0):

Close :)

```
type DropdownMenuItemWrapperProps = {
   as: Parameters<typeof React.createElement>[0],
   // other props type
}

const DropdownMenuItemWrapper = ({
  as = "div",
  to,
  target,
  onClick,
  active,
  children
}: DropdownMenuItemWrapperProps) => React.createElement(as, { to, target, onClick }, children);
```

Comment: I am getting error on that second params `{to, target, onClick}`
`No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ to: string; target: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'to' does not exist in type 'Attributes'`